# install mod_session for Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2

Sorry for the basic question, how do I install mod_session for Apache 2.2 IN RHEL5? I've tried searching but all I've found is configuration documents.

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: My server is an Apache HTTP server, version 2.2. The OS is a Redhat OS, version 5.4

Comment: Whyever do you not use apache 2.4?  It's much better, as it allows you to do things like mitigate certain SSL attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the apache documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_session.html

> Compatibility:    Available in Apache 2.3 and later

So you will need to upgrade your apache first and afterward enable the module

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But at the workplace, we use Apache 2.2. I needed session handling for my app hosted on the apache server. The app will later be shifted to another machine. A module install would be fine but an upgrade would not be possible. That's why I'm looking for an individual module install for apache 2.2

Comment: Then I think you will have to download the sources and compile the module on your own. But I think that this will cause heavy pain because you will have to modify the source code to be compatible with 2.2 - Other question: Which kind of appliction are you hosting? Maybe the session handling is covered by itself?!

Comment: I have downloaded mod_session.c. I'm not sure how to proceed after that. My app is on the framework web.py. It supports session handling and I'm using the file store. The issue is that Apache is creating a new session id for every request. So my sessions are as long as one request because my framework creates a new session file on every request. If there is some way to link the session id to the domain, that would resolve my issue.

Comment: Sounds like your `web.py` is not configured correctly. I think mod_session won't resolve your problem. But I think you will have to ask some python experts here. So maybe retag your question

Comment: Is your app running in `debug` mode? Please check the documentation: http://webpy.org/cookbook/sessions

Comment: The app runs fine on the web.py integrated server. The issue is on the Apache server. I now added the line web.config.debug = False and ran the app on Apache. Now I have only one session across the requests. However, my app still fails because on every request, the session variables are going to the default values rather than the value assigned to them before the submit.

Comment: I think you will have to give us additional code or post it at stackoverflow.com - I assume that apache has nothing to do with it

Comment: Yeah.. I guess you are right... I already have it posted on stack overflow.. no responses there also.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747684/session-variable-appears-to-lose-value-in-web-py-application-over-apache

Comment: Okay. Let's continue discussion there and close this on serverfault